# How can I scramble words from a text file after already randomly choosing a word from text

Tags: java

My words from the text file are already printing out randomly, but how can I get the words to scramble from text. I have a seperate class called ScrambleWords. I'm
stuck on calling the scrambleWord method from the other class. My code is below.

```
public class WordShuffle extends ScrambleWords {

    protected Scanner file;
    protected ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void openFile(){

        try {
            file = new Scanner(new File("words.txt"));


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File Not Found");
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("IOEXCEPTION");
        }
    }

    public void readFile(){

        Random r = new Random();

        while(file.hasNextLine()){
            words.add(file.nextLine());
            }

            String randomWord = words.get(r.nextInt(words.size()));
            Collections.shuffle(words);
            System.out.println(randomWord);

        //}
    }

    public void closeFile(){
        file.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //ArrayList<String> inputString = words;

        WordShuffle shuff = new WordShuffle();
        //ScrambleWords mix = new ScrambleWords();

        shuff.openFile();
        System.out.print("Before: ");
        shuff.readFile();


        //System.out.println("After: ");

        shuff.closeFile();
    }

}

public class ScrambleWords {

    public static String scrambleWord(Random r, String inputString){

        //convert string to char array
        char a[] = inputString.toCharArray();

        for(int i = 0; i < a.length-1; i++){
            int j = r.nextInt(a.length-1);

            //swap letters
            char temp = a[i]; a[i] = a[j]; a[j] = temp;
        }

        return new String(a);
    }

}
```

Comment: _I'm stuck on calling the scrambleWord method from the other class_.. Are you getting an error if you try to call it or is there some other problem???

Comment: Can you provide your entire source code, including imports. Then I can work on it and see what the problem is.

Comment: yeah sure, ..............the imports for the WordShuffle class are

Comment: import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

Comment: The imports for the Scramble class are ......import java.util.Random;

Comment: @MooseMan55...I just added the imports for you

Comment: No error, Im stuck on calling it @Codebender

Answer (score 0):

To actually scramble the words you would be better off using an intermediate data structure like a List to give yourself a quicker means for sorting the data.

Example:

```
public static String scrambleWords(Random r, String curWord) {
   List<Character> theWord = new ArrayList<>(curWord.length());
   for (int i = 0; i < theWord.size(); i++) {
        theWord.add(curWord.charAt(i);

   }

   Collections.shuffle(theWord);

   return new String(theWord.toArray(new Character[]));
}
```

Comment: How would I call this method from the other class

Comment: Just copy and paste the body of the above method into the body of the method in your existing code.

Comment: If I answered your question please mark as resolved for other devs on the forums